# My proof of closed range theorem: where is the mistake?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I tried to prove the closed range theorem please could someone check my proof:

Theorem: Let $H,H'$ be Hilbert spaces and $u\in B(H,H')$ and $u^\ast$ its adjoint. Then $\mathrm{im}(u)$ is closed if and only if $\mathrm{im}(u^\ast)$ is.

Proof:

Write $H' = \mathrm{im}(u) \oplus \mathrm{im}(u)^\bot$ and recall that $\mathrm{im}(u)^\bot = \mathrm{ker}(u^\ast)$. Define a map

$$ (u^\ast)' : \mathrm{im}{u}\to \mathrm{im}(u^\ast), x \mapsto u^\ast(x)$$

Then this map is a homeomorphism. Since $\mathrm{im}(u)$ is complete it follows that $\mathrm{im}(u^\ast)$ is complete and therefore closed.

Do the same for the other direction.

(I'm very unsure because I found a proof of this theorem [in these lecture notes](https://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/502.s97/functional.pdf) but the argument seems much longer and more complicated)

Comment: "Then this map is a homeomorphism." <- that needs to be shown. If $\operatorname{im} u$ is closed, so that you have the decomposition $H' = \operatorname{im} u \oplus (\operatorname{im} u)^\perp$, then you know that $(u^\ast)'$ [the restriction of $u^\ast$ to $\operatorname{im} u$] is a linear bijection, but not a priori that it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought this followed from the open mapping theorem. Doesn't it?

Comment: To apply the open mapping theorem, you need to know that $\operatorname{im} u^\ast$ is complete [which is equivalent to closed here] first.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point :/ Thank you for your help.